# How to set decimal separator in DecimalFormat to empty

Tags: java, decimalformat

I want to format a number from this 3,004 to this 30040. Or 0,034 to 340.

With DecimalFormat i cant set the Decimalseparator to ''. So how to achieve this?

```
Double test = resultSet.getDouble("somedoublefield");
DecimalFormatSymbols fts = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
fts.setDecimalSeparator('');
DecimalFormat ft = new DecimalFormat("#0.0000",fts);
```

Comment: Why don't you just multiply the number with 10000 before printing it?

Comment: To justify what @Thomas wrote: after you remove a sign from the number - basically you have a different number. That means - you performed some math on it, not formatting. Therefore, removing the sign is a math problem, not a formatter's one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create DecimalFormatSymbols  object with right Locale  you are dealing with. You can use German locale as follows

```
DecimalFormatSymbols fts = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.GERMAN);
```

Check [this](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~vaucher/Java/tutorials/Formatting.html) link.